# Android Gradle Plugin 8.0.1: How to declare crashlytics tasks dependency in build.gradle

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics

After upgrading the Android Gradle Plugin to version 8.0.1, build of AAB package failed with:

`Declare task ':app:mergeReleaseNativeLibs' as an input of ':app:injectCrashlyticsBuildIdsRelease'.`

```
   Release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        debuggable false
        manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsCollectionEnabled:"true"]
        firebaseCrashlytics {
            nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
            unstrippedNativeLibsDir "build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/Release/out/lib/"
        }
        ndk {
            debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'
        }
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
```

I put tasks.namend in `build.gradle`(Module), put I don't know exactly, where to place it there.

```
tasks.named(":app:injectCrashlyticsBuildIdsProBuild").configure { dependsOn(":app:mergeProBuildNativeLibs") }
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks
GGK